# How to find Arc length and angle for SVG shapes based on Mouse events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to rotate an irregular shape object about its **center**using mouse events.
Consider the figure at this link http://prntscr.com/7sixkt  , **Line AB** is acting as a handle which i  am using to rotate this irregular figure, square is to show BBOX  (found center of shape using **get BBox method**.
I know **A (center point coordinates)** and length of **AB (radius of BBox)**. What I cannot calculate is if I move/drag line AB as a handle to rotate shape, how to find **theta** or arc length **BC** , using arc-length formula I have 2 unknowns, **L=rθ** ( L and θ). kindly guide how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SVG, you only need to point A and point B with mouse event. The pseudo code:

1. on mousedown event, record A `(x0,y0)` and B `(x1,y1)`
2. on mouseup event, record mouse position `(x2,y2)`
3. With 3 points, you can obtain 3 lengths on the Cartesian coordinate, which in turn you can calculate value of `θ`.

With SVG, use `transform="rotate(θ)"` on the `<img....>`, the rotation is clockwise for positive values and counter clockwise for negative.

Comment: thanks a lot @Alvin  for your time and effort , considering i know 3 points, could you suggest, what is the formula i can use for finding angle, because if i connect 3 points and make a triangle it will work for angles < 180 ...for angles less than 180 , i am using **Law of cosine** but for greater than 180 degrees, i don't know the formula, any suggestions....thanks

Comment: Use atan() to convert, see my [solution](http://alkhoo-app.appspot.com/akfiddle/circle_angle.html). Check the source for `getAngle()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the point (B') where AB gets cut on a 90º angle from C you can reduce your problem with Pitagoras Theorem, as you redefine your problem to a rectangle triangle between A, B' and C whose θ angle is the same as in your initial case and the angle between AB' and B'C is 90º.

On this case, θ could be calculated as arc cos (B'C / AC)

Comment: thanks a lot @Bardo  ,  one tiny problem though, what in case if **theta** exceeds 180 degree,  in that case how to make it work ?